# How to catch touch keyboard loading event on windows 8?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8, keyboard, windows-8.1

I need to replace standard virtual touch keyboard on windows 8, 8.1. I suppose that I need to catch keyboard loading event (create a hook or something like that) and replace this standard keyboard with my own (my own application).

Any suggestions how can I do that? Should I write a windows store application or anything else? The application should be written in C# or in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own custom keyboard instead of windows 8/8.1 default keyboard please prefer the following components for WPF

No need to create any application for this purpose. The component will do all things for you.

https://wpfkb.codeplex.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32568/A-Touch-Screen-Keyboard-Control-in-WPF

It works fine with WPF applications (I didn't try this with windows store application). I think it may work with store application also, because it using the same XAML language as WPF to create control

Comment: But how does the windows will know that standard keyboard should be replaced with these ones?

Comment: you just need to show the custom keyboard right? or you want to catch that event for some other purpose ?

Comment: if you want to know how it will be replaced you need to dig into the component code. it's opensource

Comment: I just need to show the custom keyboard instead of standard. Did you test this application on Windows 8?

Comment: no i didn't test this keyboard on Windows 8, are you creating WPF application ?

Comment: if you are creating WPF application it will definitely work on win 7 /win 8/ win 8.1

Comment: Have a look at my answer